# Now that Device Central is dead, how can I test my Flash Lite applications?

Tags: flash

I'm trying to use Flash Lite to make a simple game for my girlfriend, who only has a Nokia 5530, but I just realized in CS6 Adobe killed Device Central, so there's no way for me to test it without the device (and it's supposed to be a surprise).

Is there any other way for me to test it? I know I can just export the movie and use Flash Player, but Device Central allowed me to test drag and drop and memory/processor usage for example...

tl;dr, is there an alternative to Device Central for testing Flash Lite in older devices?

Comment: I saw something like this when I read about flash the other day. I am looking it up for you. Good luck with the game. Worst case you could email her the game and test it on a computer. Just a couple of minutes, I think I can still find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New answer:

After getting more intell on the situation, I suggest installing CS5 in addition to CS6 until you no longer require use of the Device Central. It will work according to online resources. If you wish to make sure you could try superuser.com for additional advice.

Good luck making that game. :)

As you probably know CS6 allows to save projects as CS5 (with some limitations).

Old answer:

Read about: Adobe AIR mobile simulation

> Simulate common mobile application interactions like screen
>   orientation, touch gestures, and accelerometer to help speed up
>   testing.

I have not tested it. I think it looks promising.

There is a tutorial here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMCnLJylDgc

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Adobe Air emulates a generic mobile device. I can test generic functions with no specifics. And I think Adobe Air uses a different Flash version which is not Flash Lite. The worst part is that Adobe makes downgrading very difficult x_x I should better give my girlfriend a new Android phone, lol.

Comment: Wait, you can't use and older CS to work around this?

Comment: I don't think I can install CS5 while having CS6, can I?

Comment: Great news: http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r27432956-Soft-Can-CS5-and-CS6-live-in-harmony-
It seems they do live in harmony. I am guessing you install them in different folders and it will work fine. You can ask in super user if you need more advice I imagine.

Comment: Working fine at CS5.5! I think I will never understand why Adobe would remove a feature, though. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes I read about the removed/added features here:
http://cs5.org/?p=2049